# Bootstrap tabs - hidden tab height too tall

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, overflow

I'm having an issue with the Bootstrap system. I've been using it well for a while but I had to change the layout of our system page to use the tabs feature. I noticed that I'm having a problem where the hidden tab height is being automatically set to the full height of the window and NOT of the area where the tabs are.

For example, on the page, the tab section is a div that has a height of 400px. The first - active - tab is correctly doing an `overflow-y: scroll`. The div scrolls up and down and the stuff below the tab area is placed properly. However, if I click on one of the other tabs (initially hidden) the content below the tab section gets pushed way down and those sections don't scroll. I used Firebug to inspect them and the first tab has a height like 388px or something and the other two have a height of 925px, which is abou the full height of the window.

For security and legal reasons, I can't post the code such that it's duplicable online, and I'm not asking anyone to correct my code - for that reason. But I'm wondering if anyone has experienced this and if so, what did you do to fix it? I'm really just looking for a direction.